# Html 5 infinite scroll on dyinamic web page

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll page where the dimension change when I add an element, here there is an image to explain what I mean.

[image]

there is a lot of css so if needed I can add them too.

thanks

Comment: Good for you .... If you have a real specific question about the code you are writing then post it here... Read the section http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're going to have to narrow this down to specific pieces if you want to avoid having your question closed.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

1. Give your header and footer a [fixed position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning) along with a defined height.
2. Give your main body [auto overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) along with padding equal to the height of the header and footer.

Perhaps this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fr0f8gh1/1/) will give you direction. You can create your page layout similar to:

```html
<header id="header-container">
    <div id="site-header">
        Site Header
    </div>
    <div id="main-header">
        Main Header
    </div>
</header>
<footer id="footer-container">
    <div id="main-footer">
        Main Footer
    </div>
    <div id="site-footer">
        Site Footer
    </div>
</footer>
<main id="main-body">
    Main Body
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</main>
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px; /* 100px for site header, 50px for main header. */
}

#site-header {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 100px;
}

#main-header {
    background-color: #cce;
    height: 50px;
}

#footer-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px; /* 50px for site footer, 25px for main footer. */
}

#site-footer {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 50px;
}

#main-footer {
    background-color: #cce;
    height: 25px;
}

#main-body {
    margin: 150px 0 75px; /* 50px on top, 50px on bottom*/
    overflow: auto;
}
```